# Does matchmaker assign sides by tank type?

Tags: world-of-tanks

For the past week or so I've been playing almost strictly StgPzIVb, a very fun artillery to play. I played the several maps available dozens of times and I was frequently making plans "where to hide when I play the opposite side". Plans I never managed to realize.

- Airfield - always West.
- Karelia - always North
- Westfield - always North
- Mines - always South
- Siegfried Line - always South
- Widepark - always North (and I played it 20 times at the least and always died a * premature death without a safe place to hide while enemy artillery enjoyed safe kills from their neatly enclosed end.)

The moment I moved to Grille I started seeing the other sides of these maps.

What are the rules of assigning sides of the map in the game? Are the sides tiered or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the sides assigned are random, so you must have been (un)lucky to be placed on the same side every time.

Personally I remember at least playing the StgPzIVb at least once on the North side of the Mines map.

Comment: Seems the streak has ended. I've been playing Widepark three times, all of them South, all of them won.

Comment: yeah, I know its random map/side/spawn, but it doesn't seem like it. Often I get the same map and same side 3 times or more in a  row.

Answer (score 0):

Don't remember about specific position, but:

- Arty always get the same spawn position (for a specific map & game-mod).
- In default mod, heavies, meds and lights are randomly spawned.
- In King of the Hill mod, Heavies and big meds spawn near the point, and meds/lights are spawned next to the alternate route.
- (I didn't play the last mod, feel free to edit my anwser if you know it.)

Comment: I don't believe this answers the questions, as SF is asking about the north vs south team assignments, not the positions you get on the map within a team.

Comment: Well it is possible i misunderstood what he exactly meant, since English is not my native language...

Comment: I've never come across, and Google doesn't find a "King of the Hill" mod. Also, spawning is done server side, so how can a mod change it?

Comment: @JeremyMiles I don't know the english exact name as my game client is in French. The one i meant by KOTH is the one where the two teams captures the same point.